# Replacing string in txt using foreach

Tags: c#

I'm trying to replace a string in a text file with everything there is in the other file. For my html Email variable. 
But whenever i try to run the foreach, it gives me the error that it can convert char to string. How would one go about doing this in a different way?

```
        StreamReader myreader = new StreamReader("VUCresult.txt");
        StreamReader myreaderhtml = new StreamReader("htmlemail.html");
        string lines = myreader.ReadToEnd();
        string htmlmailbody = myreaderhtml.ReadToEnd();


        if (lines == "Der er ikke nogen udmeldinger idag")
        {
            htmlmailbody.Replace("ingen", lines);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string s in lines)
            {
                htmlmailbody = htmlmailbody.Replace("Row2", s);
            }
        htmlmailbody = htmlmailbody.Replace("Row1", lines);
        htmlmailbody = htmlmailbody.Replace("Row3", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: `foreach (string s in lines)` and `lines` is of type `string` - what makes you think that iterating a string would give you more strings?

Comment: I see your point sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `foreach` over a very long string (that happens to include newlines); that will return you each individual character.

To get all the lines in a file (as a collection) just use [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    string htmlmailbody;        
    using StreamReader myreaderhtml = new StreamReader("htmlemail.html"))
    {
       htmlmailbody = myreaderhtml.ReadToEnd();
    }
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("VUCresult.txt");

    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
       ...
    }
```

Your original `if` check won't make sense here since you have a collection of lines instead of the entire file, and your second replace statements in the else won't make sense either. You need to decide which thing you are really trying to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the foreach here as lines is a string already and calling foreach on it would make variable 's' a char. What's more, statement s.ToString() does nothing as it returns a string, leaving s itself unchanged.

Furthermore, consider enclosing readers in 'using' statement.